# Rails 3.2 - Query to extract records not working properly - Is this syntax correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql

I got 2 models. One called `Header` and another one called `Alarm`

Alarm has a column called `keyword`.
Header have 4 columns called `title_en, title_es, title_eu, title_fr`

I would like to compare these `4 columns` of a given `Header` against the `keyword` field for every single `Alarm`. This should extract the `Alarms` which match somehow any of the titles.

The query I have built(see below) works in a weird way. I have tried with some fake data:

```
Alarm1.keyword = 'foo'
Header1.title_es = 'foo'
Header2.title_en = 'foo'
Header3.title_en = 'foo'
```

This query returns Alarm1 only with Header2 and Header3. Why does not work for Header1? Anything to do with `title_es`.

```
@header = Header.find(somegivenheader)
@alarms =  Alarm.where((["CAST(alarms.keyword as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", @header.title_en] || ["CAST(alarms.keyword as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", @header.title_es] || ["CAST(alarms.keyword as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", @header.title_fr] || ["CAST(alarms.keyword as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", @header.title_eu]))
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think those where clauses are being ORed together as you expect. Take a look at the resulting SQL in the console by appending `.to_sql` to `Alarm.where(...)`.

Or, try something like:

```
Alarm.where("keyword in (?)", [@header.title_es, @header.title_fr, @header.title_eu])
```

Comment: That works perfect!!! Thanks a lot! When you say 'take a look' when appending that. Where am I suppose to see the results? console?

Comment: @SergioNekora, yes, the console is your friend when debugging sql. You can take the sql itself and paste into your sql server's console to test it there as well.